# regression for percentages - different results in r, python and matlab

Tags: python, r, matlab, regression, percentage

I have percentages and need to calculate a regression. According to basic statistics using logistic regression is better than OLS as percentages invalidate the requirement of a continuous and unconstraint value space.

So far, so good.
However, I get different results in R, Python, and Matlab. In fact, Matlab even reports significant values where python will not.

My models look like:

```
R:
summary(glm(foo ~ 1 + bar + baz  , family = "binomial", data = <<data>>))

Python via statsmodels:
smf.logit('foo ~ 1 + bar + baz', <<data>>).fit().summary()

Matlab:
fitglm(<<data>>,'foo ~ 1 + bar + baz','Link','logit')
```

where Matlab currently produces the best results.

Could there be different initialization values? Different solvers? Different settings for alphas when computing p-values?
How can I get the same results at least in similar numeric ranges or same features detected as significant? I do not require exact equal numeric output.

### edit

the summary statistics

```
python:
Dep. Variable:  foo No. Observations:   104
Model:  Logit   Df Residuals:   98
Method: MLE Df Model:   5
Date:   Wed, 28 Aug 2019    Pseudo R-squ.:  inf
Time:   06:48:12    Log-Likelihood: -0.25057
converged:  True    LL-Null:    0.0000
LLR p-value:    1.000
coef    std err z   P>|z|   [0.025  0.975]
Intercept   -16.9863    154.602 -0.110  0.913   -320.001    286.028
bar -0.0278 0.945   -0.029  0.977   -1.880  1.824
baz 18.5550 280.722 0.066   0.947   -531.650    568.760
a   9.9996  153.668 0.065   0.948   -291.184    311.183
b   0.6757  132.542 0.005   0.996   -259.102    260.454
d   0.0005  0.039   0.011   0.991   -0.076  0.077


R:
glm(formula = myformula, family = "binomial", data = r_x)

Deviance Residuals: 
      Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max  
-0.046466  -0.013282  -0.001017   0.006217   0.104467  

Coefficients:
                                       Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)                          -1.699e+01  1.546e+02  -0.110    0.913
bar                     -2.777e-02  9.449e-01  -0.029    0.977
baz                               1.855e+01  2.807e+02   0.066    0.947
a                       1.000e+01  1.537e+02   0.065    0.948
b                       6.757e-01  1.325e+02   0.005    0.996
d  4.507e-04  3.921e-02   0.011    0.991

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 0.049633  on 103  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 0.035684  on  98  degrees of freedom
AIC: 12.486

Matlab:
Estimated Coefficients:
                                            Estimate         SE         tStat        pValue  
                                            _________    __________    ________    __________

    (Intercept)                               -21.044         3.315     -6.3483    6.8027e-09
    bar                        -0.033507      0.022165     -1.5117       0.13383
    d    0.0016149    0.00083173      1.9416      0.055053
    baz                                    21.427        6.0132      3.5632    0.00056774
    a                            14.875        3.7828      3.9322    0.00015712
    b                           -1.2126        2.7535    -0.44038       0.66063


104 observations, 98 error degrees of freedom
Estimated Dispersion: 1.25e-06
F-statistic vs. constant model: 7.4, p-value = 6.37e-06
```

Comment: There's a huge number of possible things that could be happening here. My guess is it might be about how predictors are being treated, but without at least the actual summary tables it's very hard to say.

Comment: I added the summary statistics.

Comment: Are your percentages the `foo` variable? If so, I'm not sure how logistic regression is the appropriate method since your y variable should be binary.

Comment: I'm not sure you can trust any of these results, the estimated coefficients and standard errors for some predictors are enormous which suggests something is seriously wrong.  It might be the way your data is set up, or you might have something like [separation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11109/how-to-deal-with-perfect-separation-in-logistic-regression) going on.

Comment: Correct:  `foo ~  ....` is the percentage. And indeed, this is why scikit-learn refuses to work. But similar to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/284843/percentage-as-dependent-variable-in-multiple-linear-regression it should work.

Comment: Indeed. This is again correct. R does not complain, and python /statsmodels warns for quasi separation.

Comment: But again: in Matlab, the p-values seem to be smaller. And I do not understand the difference.

Comment: The estimates don't seem THAT different to me. Perhaps you need to revise your understanding of p-values. My recommendation would be https://www.nature.com/news/statisticians-issue-warning-over-misuse-of-p-values-1.19503 and https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00031305.2016.1154108.

Comment: Interesting. Could it also be handled the other way round? I.e. Allowing dispersion in R?

Comment: Very interesting. However https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77760/perfect-separation-error-message-for-glm-with-binomial-but-not-with-quasibinomia claim that the difference should not be this large

Comment: I can reproduce that when switching to quasibinomial that results similar to Matlab are produced. Thanks a lot. Now I just need to figure out which family is more correct. Is there some indication when to use which?

Comment: I do not know yet. Just changed the family. I will need to do further research. Also note: so far I only checked that the results reported a significant are aligned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not actually using the binomial distribution in the MATLAB case. You are specifying the link function, but the distribution remains its default value for a normal distribution, which will not give you the expected logistic fit, at least if the sample sizes for the percentages are small. It is also giving you lower p-values, because the normal distribution is less constrained in its variance than the binomial distribution is.

You need to specify the `Distribution` argument to `Binomial`:

```
fitglm(<<data>>, 'foo ~ 1 + bar + baz', 'Distribution', 'binomial ', 'Link', 'logit')
```

The R and Python code seem to match rather well.